# JSQMessaging using a avatar to identify a specific messageId with the avatar being adjacent to the message

Tags: ios, swift

[Picture of a chat room](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmE3V.png).  If I wanted to identify a specific messageId by the avatar next to it how would that be possible? For example if I click on the avatar to the right of that specific image how can I directly do something to that specific message without affecting the others such as change a color of the text or bubble of it or edit that message?

Comment: I would recommend you also to provide your own ideas how to solve your problem. Even if they don't work, it can be useful for those, who is going to help you.

Comment: I was thinking of somehow using:                                                                    " collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, didTapMessageBubbleAt indexPath: IndexPath!)  " in order to tell if a avatar was clicked on and from that point show how use the messageId given by each message and use that as a form of identifying a message.